# Postgres identify pattern in string across multi rows in a group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that groups rows together by two specific ids, and orders them by a action date. Along with this, a string of if the action date was added or removed is included.

I'd like to identify result sets that follow a pattern other than 'added' -> 'removed' -> ect. such as 'added' -> 'removed' -> 'added' -> 'added'.

If this was a set of data grouped together, I'd like to identify that as a pattern.

[image]

For example, I can use this query

```
select id_a , id_b, string_agg(action_key, ', ') as agg_field from test_table
group by id_a, id_b, link_type 
order by agg_field desc
```

to get the column agg_field column as

```
'added, removed, added, added, removed'
```

but I'm not sure how to identify that result set in the group by as compared to

```
'added, removed, added, removed'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep only rows where there is a change:

```
select id_a , id_b, string_agg(action_key, ', ') as agg_field
from (select t.*,
             lag(action_key) over (partition by id_a, id_b order by action_date) as prev_action_key
      from test_table t
     ) t
where prev_action_key is distinct form action_key
group by id_a, id_b, link_type 
order by agg_field desc;
```

I would recommend adding `order by action_date` to the `string_agg()`.

Comment: Didn't know lag() was a thing, very cool solution and worked great. Thanks!